# How can I make this html5 video appear on mobile?

Tags: javascript, css, html, video, html5-video

I'm trying to make this video on my website appear as a material design card before you press play, it works on desktop but the problem is that when its on mobile it does this weird setting where it shows the play button and hides the video until you click it then it turns your phone into a video mode.. How can I override this setting in either the  tag or CSS??? Thank you.

```
<video class="hoverable video-mask" id="video1" width="100%" onmouseover="this.play()" onmouseout="this.pause()">
                        <source src='videos/suntegra.mp4' type='video/mp4'/>
                        <source src='videos/suntegra.webm' type='video/webm'/>
                        Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

Comment: Can you post some code please and show us what you have tried?

Comment: just did thanks for the advice

Comment: i think it's supposed to be like that, nothing to be done about it...

Comment: From what I can tell, it all depends on the mobile browser you are using. I have seen custom flash browsers override this but you have to pay for them.